# Can mod-rewrite parse/modify strings RETURNED to the client from a reverse-proxied server?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Apache newb here.

It's clear that I can use mod-rewrite to change URLs being passed through from the client to the ultimate destination server via an apache-as-reverse-proxy and a rewrite rule.

Can rewrite rules work in the other direction, too? For example, if my destination server is appending something to the URL (`http://foo/?someparam=true&removeme=now`) that I want to remove before the string is returned to the client, can mod-rewrite do this for me, too? I'd want to turn the previous string into `http://foo?someparam=true`

Thanks much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod_rewrite won't do this for you. You'll need to use something like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) that will take content returned from a reverse proxy and rewrite *the content*.

The webthing link has a tutorial for how to set one up.